# What does a double percentage sign (%%) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

To give a little context, I am working with BigCommerce theme template files right now, and I do not understand some of the syntax.

They use a double percentage sign to wrap certain things in the document. An example:

```
<!-- Include visitor tracking code (if any) -->
%%GLOBAL_TrackingCode%%
%%GLOBAL_DesignModeStyleSheet%%
%%GLOBAL_HeaderImageStyle%%
```

They will also be included in source attributes sometimes, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_TPL_PATH%%/js/imagesLoaded.js"></script>
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the %% means.

Hopefully that will give enough info to answer the question, if anything else is needed let me know. If this is not a JavaScript thing like I assumed, feel free to move it to the appropriate category.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That isn't Javascript. It's probably markers so that BigCommerce can replace them with some kind of configurable value. Ex: `%%GLOBAL_TPL_PATH%%` might be replaced with `/my/server/path`

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea what language they may use to swap those values out? This stuff is fascinating to me, so I'm trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: That could be done by any language. It isn't a programming language; just markers. Why do you want to know what language they use?

Comment: BigCommerce uses it to include other templates (panels, snippets, see more at developer.bigcommerce.com) or to inject values from the core php code base. The templating is built on top of PHP

Comment: I would like to know in case I ever have to deal with markers myself. I'm trying to teach myself how to be a software engineer, and would like to learn the front and back end technologies associated with anything I come across. So just curiosity I guess.

Comment: @Alyss Thank you, I believe that is what I needed to give some direction of what to learn next.

Comment: And only slightly less annoying than having a simple `<?= GLOBAL_TPL_PATH; ?>` instead of obscure template BS that has to be parsed and run with a slight overhead from regular PHP defined constants. *shakes head*

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie So using a template system like this rather than just having the proper paths in the HTML is going to make the entire system run slower, correct? If that's the case, why do it, for security?

Comment: It MIGHT make the system run slower - it IS another layer on the cake. It might not be a lot slower, think milliseconds, but if there are a million users, those milliseconds tends to add up. Security? None, whatsoever - there is no difference between these and other constants. The only thing is that they are a little easier to enter, and doesn't "show" that much code (as adding `<?php echo` or `<?=` does. It also depends on HOW these are interpreted. Does the program output static HTML which is then served to users, or are these tags interpreted on the fly on every page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a templating tool, that the people who made the template would change according to what they want to put in there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not JavaScript, it's clearly a templating language's marker for variables.